# laravel 5 get data from database class not found

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have created two models in laravel 5, Cat and Breed

Cat...

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Breed;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Cat extends Model {
    protected $fillable = array('name','date_of_birth','breed_id');
    public function breed(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Breed');
    }
}
?>
```

Breed...

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Cat;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Breed extends Model {
    public $timestamps = false;
    public function cats(){
        return $this->hasMany('Cat');
    }
}
?>
```

then I migrated the tables (cats and breeds) and seeded cats table with some data, the table was populated without any errors (viewed from phpmyadmin)

then in routes.php, I dropped this code,

```
Route::get('cats/breeds/{name}', function($name){
    $breed = Breed::whereName($name)->with('cats')->first();
    return View::make('cats.index')
        ->with('breed', $breed)
        ->with('cats', $breed->cats);
});
```

when I load the page test.com/cats/breeds/persian this error pops... (test.com is my virtualhost, persian is a data inserted)

FatalErrorException in Model.php line 895: Class 'Cat' not found

the lines 891 - 900 are,

```
public function hasMany($related, $foreignKey = null, $localKey = null)
    {
        $foreignKey = $foreignKey ?: $this->getForeignKey();

        $instance = new $related;

        $localKey = $localKey ?: $this->getKeyName();

        return new HasMany($instance->newQuery(), $this, $instance->getTable().'.'.$foreignKey, $localKey);
    }
```

I included,

```
use App\Models\Cat;
```

in the Model.php file, but this error persists, please help

Comment: Try `php artisan optimize` this will generate optimized class loader, which may help you

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
return $this->belongsTo('Breed');
```

with

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Breed');
```

and

```
return $this->hasMany('Cat');
```

with

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Cat');
```

also remove `use App\Models\Cat;` From your Model.php

Comment: thanks for your time, there pops another error,

ErrorException in 67019d844dbed4a0b1c3961e3aa7f4a6 line 10: Trying to get property of non-object

line 10...

    {{{$cat->name}}}

Comment: sorry, the error is

"Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found."
"NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 143:"